# Alert box not being called upon button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a fairly simple code, a button click event, with the first line being a message box.
When the button is clicked, the messagebox is not called.

```
protected void btnSubmitToCRM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ValidateCoreValue())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!ValidateOtherAppLicenses())
        {
            return;
        }

        GetTicketRequesterInfo();

        SendCRMEmail();

        ClearTextBoxes(Page.Controls);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('btnSubmitToCRM_Click - 1" + ex.Message + "');", true);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the idea is that the submit button throws up a javascript alert?  Well, you would need to register the client script in a different event than the one that is fired when the button is clicked.

Think about the order of events here.  By the time you get into the btnSubmitToCRM_Click function the client has already posted back to the server.  Then you're trying to register the event on the client side to throw up the alert.  Well, at that point it's too late.  The client has already clicked the button.  The RegisterStartupScript method inserts Javascript into the page when whatever event it is called in is fired.  So, generally that has to happen when the page loads.

I'd say try throwing the RegisterStartupScript call into your page load event and see if that helps.

Update:  So, if the intention is to find out what is going on in the code on the test server then you should either attach a remote debugger, write out exceptions to a common log using something like NLog or you could write out the exception message to an ASP:Label control on the page.

Comment: I updated my code above. My intention is to see why "SendCRMEmail(); " is not called. At the moment I don't know if the code execution is kicked out at some point within the code block;

Comment: You could attach a debugger and set a breakpoint to see whether the function is called.  From what I see above your code for the alert is still not going to work because you're registering a client side script for the button click after the button click has already happened.

Comment: The issue is happening on the test server. Everything is working fine on my localhost;

Comment: Attach a remote debugger or write any exceptions out to an exception log using something like NLog.  Either that or if you are using web controls you can put an asp:label on the page and then in your exception block you can write the exception message out to that label.

Comment: Brilliant, Harv. Absolutely brilliant!